# Laravel 6 Multiple File preview with remove

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I want to ask,

so I have a form whose contents one of which is to upload multiple files, then after I browse the file, then the file will appear (preview),

then the user will have access to choose the file to upload when it is not wanted then there is a delete button for wrong one file.

then after all okay, then the form will be uploaded.

then after that the user will be able to edit the file again through another page without deleting the old file.

this is what I want,

1. user fills in the input form
2. when in the input file field, the user can select several files
3. Then after clicking OK, the selected file will be displayed
4. The user can delete one of the unwanted files
5. after all okay the user submit the form to db

like the display on [wetransfer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zy5Ny.png)

can anyone teach me?

Comment: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: thankyou for your answer, but how i get result without plugin?